# EXCEL - ELEGANT FORMULAS

Tags: microsoft-excel

Olá,
Preciso de ajuda para criar uma fórmula mais elegante do que a que apresento abaixo:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C11>=3302000;C11<=3303999);AND(C11>=3602000;C11<=3603999));
$B$3;IF(OR(AND(C11>=3402000;C11<=3403999);AND(C11>=3702000;C11<=3703999));
$B$4;IF(OR(AND(C11>=3121000;C11<=3121999);AND(C11>=3181000;C11<=3191999);
AND(C11>=3131000;C11<=3137999));$B$5;IF(OR(AND(C11>=3122000;C11<=3122999);
AND(C11>=3281000;C11<=3291999);AND(C11>=3231000;C11<=3237999));
$B$6;IF(C11="N/A";"N/A";C11)))))
```

O que a fórmula precisa de fazer é ver se o valor de C11 está nos envelopes de valores da imagem e, se estiver, colocar na célula B11 o nome do envelope.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugestões?
Obrigado.

Comment: Quando os intervalos são sequenciais e únicos, fica bem fácil de fazer o que você quer meramente criando uma lista com os limites superiores (com duas só colunas, vc coloca em A os nomes dos envelopes e em B o valor máximo do range que pertence ao nome em A) e usando [PROCV](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/PROCV-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-PROCV-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) com o último parâmetro igual a Verdadeiro. Como não é o seu caso (porque você tem vários intervalos para um mesmo envelope), a melhor solução é mesmo usar VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Minha primeira sugestão é que você separe cada valor dos "Envelope Range" em 2 células. Por exemplo,  na célula C3 você colocou 3302000-3303999. Isso seria separado em uma célula com 3302000 e outra com 3303999. Dessa forma você não precisa escrever os valores manualmente na sua fórmula. Isso deixa a fórmula "inteligente" para futuras alterações no valores. Da forma como você fez, toda vez que altera algum valor nas faixas de busca, vai ter que mexer na sua fórmula.

Minha outra sugestão, como sua fórmula é longa e complexa (já trabalhei várias vezes assim e sei como é chato e fácil de se perder), é trabalhar como um função pública usando VBA. Fica mais organizado. Você chama a funcção na célula e passa algum parâmetro, caso seja necessário. Todo o processamento fica organizado dentro do código VBA.

Comment: A resposta tem potencial, mas ela é insuficiente pra ajudar o autor da pergunta. Se você postar um exemplo, que seja mínimo, do que está sugerindo, aí ganha o meu +1. :)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, poderia separar, conforme sugerido pelo colega. Uma forma simples de separar é usando o let ou o right e abrindo outras colunas. No seu caso terás que abrir as colunas de "F" até "K" e colocar a fórmulas intercaladas, por exemplo:

```
'Na coluna "F"
=left(C3;7)

'Na coluna "G"
=right(C3;7)

'Na coluna "H"
=left(D3;7)

'Na coluna "I"
=right(D3;7)

'Na coluna "J"
=left(E3;7)

'Na coluna "K"
=right(E3;7)
```

Depois você deve copiar as fórmulas para baixo.
Todas estas colunas terão que ter o mesmo nome: "Load Case ID" - na linha 2

Aí você faz um index match das célula C11 para baixo, a fórmula é essa:

```
=index($B$3:$B$6;;match(B11;$B$2:$K$6;0))
```

isso deve dar um jeito no que você precisa, sua única preocupação terá que ser arrumar a fórmula cada vez que uma das duas tabelas tiver linhas adicionadas a elas. pois você vai ter que alterar o range final da fórmula.